# Sending a value from JavaScript to JSP (with jQuery)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, integration

Right now I have a JSP page that allows to sort some items, when is ready and a link is clicked a JavaScript function converts all the info into XML (text in a variable), after this i need to send this XML to the JSP page again, i tried putting the info in a hidden input and submitting the form, sending with $.post and a few more jQuery functions but nothing worked.
Any ideas?

In my JSP I'm reading the post like this:

```
<% out.println(request.getParameter("data")); %>
```

This doesn't work:

```
xml = "<xml></xml>";
$("#form").submit(function(){
   alert("JS: " + $("#data").text());
   $("#data").text(xml);
});
```

This either:

```
xml = "<xml></xml>";
$("#data").text(xml);
$("#form").submit();
```

And replacing .text with .html doesn't work too.
Any ideas are welcome, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably going the wrong way here. You didn't provide the html code, but I assume it is something like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" id="data" />
</form>
```

If that is correct, then you should say `$("#data").val(xml);` instead of `text()` or `html()` as those change the matched thing with text or html you provide. This should work for your current solution.

Also I'd propose to look at jQuery's `$.post()` and others as an alternative to packing everything as xml unless this is really what you want on the backend. It could be easier to just make up a javascript object with all the values keyed by some names and pass it on to one of jQuery's `$.post(), $.get()`, etc. like this:

```
var values = {name: "John", surname: "Doe"};
values.age = 25;
$.post("index.jsp", values); // this will result in a post with 3 variables: name, surname, age
```

Actually it only occured to me now that you can also send your xml this way (unless you prefer your way of doing things):

```
$.post("index.jsp", {data: "<xml><whatever-else-needs-to-be-in-here/></xml>"});
```

You might want to enlighten yourself more here: [Ajax @ jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

Answer (score 2):

Trying using the [jQuery Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) API - you can use it to send arbitrary data via GET or POST and you don't need to set up a hidden form or anything.

Comment: Yes, we don't submit forms, like we traditionally do. A sound suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use an XMLHttpRequest to send the data.  This can be done with our without user interaction on an element such as a form submit button.  jQuery has functionality built in for assisting with such requests.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Comment: Suggesting another library is like creating a mess here. JQuery is as good as Prototype in making AJAX calls, if not better.